# Get response after Android Wear Action

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to develop with [Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html). I tried all the tutorial provided in the documentation, but now I want to try to do something smarter. I'm trying to get back the text that user says (with emulator written by computer keyboard), so I made it with this code:

```
protected void voiceNotification() {

        // Crete intent for the response action
        Intent replyIntent = new Intent(this, ReplyActivity.class);

        // Adding intent to pending intent
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                replyIntent, 0);

        // Build the notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder replyNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this);
        replyNotificationBuilder
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_btn_speak_now);
        replyNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Messaggio");
        replyNotificationBuilder.setContentText("Testo del messaggio");
        replyNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(replyPendingIntent);
        replyNotificationBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);
        replyNotificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        replyNotificationBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        replyNotificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000 });
        replyNotificationBuilder.setTicker("Hai una nuova notifica!");

        // Create remote input
        RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY)
                .setLabel(getResources().getString(R.string.reply_label))
                .build();

        // Create the wearable notification
        Notification replyNotification = new WearableNotifications.Builder(replyNotificationBuilder)
            .addRemoteInputForContentIntent(remoteInput)
            .build();

        // Get the instance of NotificationManagerCompat and send my notification
        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(0, replyNotification);
    }
```

With this code on the emulator I'm getting 2 views: one with the text of my notification and a second one in which I can answer to notification with voice (keyboard with emulator). It's working all good, but I want to know if it's possible to get the text I said (wrote with emulator) to do something in my application (I saw on the emulator display that after I said/wrote somethings it appears 2 button "Edit" and "Send", so I think that with button "Send" I can get the text in my application to do something). I try to find out something in the documentation, but I don't find nothing. I hope you can help me to get this text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to implement a Broadcast-receiver that listens to the pendingIntent you defined - the reply from the user will be passed in an extra string you defined in the RemoteInput - in your case this would be `EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY`.

You might want to have a look at these two files someone posted on GitHub in order to understand what is going on.

http://git.io/emKcrw

http://git.io/_PRW_w

Comment: This looks great, thank you I will try to learn it and implement in my demo app :)